# Swiftui view flutters during drag

Tags: swiftui, gesture

I am trying to enable drag and scale in the same view.  I have noticed that the drag code must preceded the scale code.
My problem is that when the user drags, the view flutters.  How can I fix this?

```swift
struct ImageContainer: View {
    
    @State private var viewModel:ViewModel = .shared
    @State private var currentZoom = 0.0
    @State private var totalZoom = 1.0
    @State private var isDragging = false
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        viewModel.image
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                 .onChanged { value in
                     offset = value.translation
                 }
                  .onEnded { _ in
                      withAnimation {
//                          offset = .zero
                          isDragging = false
                      }
                  }
            )
            .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
            .scaleEffect(currentZoom + totalZoom)
                       .gesture(
                           MagnifyGesture()
                               .onChanged { value in
                                   currentZoom = value.magnification - 1
                               }
                               .onEnded { value in
                                   totalZoom += currentZoom
                                   currentZoom = 0
                               }
                       )
                       .accessibilityZoomAction { action in
                           if action.direction == .zoomIn {
                               totalZoom += 1
                           } else {
                               totalZoom -= 1
                           }
                       }

                       .clipped()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the `.offset` modifier above the `.gesture` modifier:

```swift
viewModel.image
    .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height) // <- BEFORE the drag gesture
    .gesture(
        DragGesture()

        // everything else as before
```

Comment: That works!  Thank you.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it! Perhaps you could mark the answer as accepted, please?